# connect woocommerce products to posts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce on my wordpress site. 
I am selling paintings. The products are paintings. 
I have a list of artists as posts. Each artist is one post. 
I would like to connect the posts and products so I can show the artist's name on the painting page and the user can click on the name and it takes them to the artist post. 
How do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

This is an example of how to add a custom field in WooCommerce product general tab. Since artists are posts ( category is not specified ), it will collect links for all posts and place them in a dropdown. The value of this field will be visible on the single product page below the price ( you can open the `content-single-product.php` file in WooCommerce theme, to see the actions for single product template, and functions attached, and change the priority of woocommerce_product_artist function if you want to change the place where the link will appear ).

```
<?php

add_action( 'admin_init', 'woocommerce_custom_admin_init' );

function woocommerce_custom_admin_init() {

    // display fields
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woocommerce_add_custom_general_fields' );

    // save fields
    add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_save_custom_general_fields' );

}

function woocommerce_add_custom_general_fields() {

    // creating post array for the options ( id => title)
    $posts = array( '' => __( 'Select Artist' ) );
    array_walk( get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => -1 ) ), function( $item ) use ( &$posts ) {
        $posts[ $item->ID ] = $item->post_title;
    } );

    // creating dropdown ( woocommerce will sanitize all values )
    echo '<div class="options_group">';
    woocommerce_wp_select(
        array(
            'id' => '_artist',
            'label' => __( 'Artist' ),
            'options' => $posts
        )
    );
    echo '</div>';

}


function woocommerce_save_custom_general_fields( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // validate id of artist page and save
    if ( isset( $_POST['_artist'] ) ) {
        $value = filter_input( INPUT_POST, '_artist', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array( 'options' => array( 'min_range' => 0 ) ) );       
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_artist', $value );        
    }

}

add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_custom_init' );

function woocommerce_custom_init() {    

    // hook the woocommerce_product_artist function on to woocommerce_single_product_summary action ( priority 15 )
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_product_artist', 15 );

}

function woocommerce_product_artist() {
    global $post;

    // get the artist page id and show in template ( if exists )
    $artist_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_artist', true );

    if ( $artist_id ) : 
    ?>
        <div class="product-artist"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $artist_id ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $artist_id ); ?></a></div>

    <?php endif;
}

?>
```

Comment: I get a _Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference_ error, so I changed your code to: `$artists = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => -1 ) ) ; array_walk( $artists, ...`

Comment: Thank you! You saved my time :) As well as comment of Christian.